# Testng Boolean Assertions java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, reportng

I get this error while running the Testng program:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.org.dnb.po.test.loginpagePOTest.verifyLoginpagecontrols(loginpagePOTest.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
```

I have two classes one for definition(class-1) and other is test(class-2)

Class 1 :

```
public static List<WebElement> unameBox1= driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']"));
public static boolean unameboxIT = unameBox1.size() > 0;
```

Class2:

```
@Test(priority=1)
public void verifyLoginpagecontrols(){

    Assert.assertTrue(unameboxIT); // Always goes into Exception as shown above
}
```

kindly help

Comment: static variables are evaluated when class is loaded, hence any exception in evaluation of a static variable is wrapped to an ExceptionInInitializerError... can u reverify "public static List<WebElement> unameBox1= driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']"));" i'm pretty sure it might null or something...hence evaluation"unameBox1.size() > 0" is throwing this error...

Comment: It's not Null. Webdriver can find it's location and enter the values